# Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I'm not sure how to fix the error I'm getting when trying to run this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class P3_3 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        int number = in.nextInt();
        if (number < 0) number *= -1;
        if (number >= 10 && number < 100)
        {
            number = 2;
        }
        else if (number >= 100 && number < 1000)
        {
            number = 3;
        }
        else if (number >= 1000 && number < 10000)
        {
            number = 4;
        }
        else if (number >= 10000 && number < 100000)
        {
            number = 5;
        }
        else if (number >= 100000 && number < 1000000)
        {
            number = 6;
        }
        else if (number >= 1000000 && number < 10000000)
        {
            number = 7;
        }
        else if (number >= 10000000 && number < 100000000)
        {
            number = 8;
        }
        else if (number >= 100000000 && number < 1000000000)
        {
            number = 9;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Number is greater than 10 billion.");
        }
        System.out.printf("%d has ", number + "digits.");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to print how many digits the number has, by checking whether the number is `>= 10, >= 100` and so on...
I run the code and I'm able to input an int but once I input it and press enter all I get it an error and can't seem to see what I have done wrong. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
System.out.printf("%d has ", number + "digits.");
```

the `%d` format specifier requires an integer to be passed as second parameter to `printf`, but by concatenating `number` and `"digits."`, you actually passed a `String`.

Fixed version:

```
System.out.printf("has %d digits ", number);
```

note that you cannot print both the original number and the number of digits, because you overwrote one with the other in the `number` variable. Maybe use two different ones.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last printf to:

```
System.out.printf("number has %d digits ", number);
```

Try to append all the string together and use specifier i.e.

```
System.out.printf("blah %d blah ", value).
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, the issue was in the print statement. A better approach, instead of using all the if statements you should use the log10 method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        int number = in.nextInt();
        if (number < 0) number *= -1;
        System.out.printf("%d has %d digits\n", number, (int)Math.log10(number) + 1 );
}
```